# How do I generate a predictable random stream in hierarchy in c#?

Tags: random, random-seed

I am making a procedural game with hierarchy.

So object A will have 10 children.

Each child will have 10 children and so on.

Now suppose I want to give each child a random colour, and a random position (assume these are given by integers).

Therefor let X be the "ID" of an object.

Let COLOUR and POSITION be enums of type PROPERTY.

Then I want to generate random integers:

```
int GenerateRandomInteger(PROPERTY P, int childNumber);
```

So I can use:

```
int N = parentObject.GenerateRandomInteger(COLOUR, 7);
```

For example.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `GetRandomInteger` should be implemented as a *hash function*. A hash function takes arbitrary data (here, the values of `P` and `childNumber`) and outputs a hash code. For the purposes of a game:

- The hash function should have the *avalanche property*, meaning that every bit of the input affects every bit of the hash code.
- Good hash functions here include MurmurHash3 and xxHash.

This answer also assumes that `childNumber` is unique throughout the application, rather than unique for a given parent.

The resulting hash code can then be used to generate a pseudorandom color and a position (for example, the first 24 bits of the hash code can be extracted and treated as a 8-bit-per-component RGB color). But further details on how this will work will depend on what programming language you're using and what ranges are acceptable for colors and positions, which you didn't specify in your question (there are several languages that use `int`s and `enum`s, for example).